# Postscript clippath operator

Tags: postscript

I have a simple Postscript code snippet,

```
%!PS
% construct a current path, a rectangle
200 300 moveto
400 300 lineto
400 450 lineto
200 450 lineto
200 300 lineto

%sets the current path to the current clipping path.
clippath

fill
showpage
```

I expect the fill of the rectangle. Instead, I got a fill of the whole page. Why the current path is ignored in this case. If I replace clippath with clip, I get the expected fill of a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

`clippath` sets the current clipping path to the current path. So that obliterates the rectangle right there. When you replace `clippath` with `clip` that takes the current path (the rectangle you described) and makes it the clipping path while leaving a copy of the same path as the current path. For this small example the result is the same as eliminating the call to either `clippath` or `clip`. *But*, if you call `clip` here then all subsequent drawing will be restricted to this rectangle. You cannot draw outside of the rectangle anymore (unless you call `initclip` to reset the clipping path).

If we reverse the steps and call `clippath` first, then we can append new line segments to this path.

```
clippath
200 300 moveto
400 300 lineto
400 450 lineto
200 450 lineto
200 300 lineto

fill
showpage
```

But depending upon what you do with it the results may still be swamped by the larger shape.

The clipping path is initially the bounding rectangle of the medium. You can view it by running some code like this:

```
{exch =only ( )print =only ( moveto) = }
{exch =only ( )print =only ( lineto) = }
{6 -2 roll exch =only ( )print =only
 4 -2 roll exch =only ( )print =only
 exch =only ( )print =only ( curveto) = }
{(closepath) = }
pathforall
```

It's not entirely clear what result you're trying to achieve. To get just a fill of the interior of the rectangle you've described, just call `fill` and don't even mess with `clip` or `clippath`. They're just there to avoid extra work if your points go outside of the page, unless you're using them for some special effect.

```
200 300 moveto
400 300 lineto
400 450 lineto
200 450 lineto
200 300 lineto

fill
showpage
```

Note that if you want to stroke the rectangle instead of fill, it's important to use `closepath` to get that last corner to look nice.

```
200 300 moveto
400 300 lineto
400 450 lineto
200 450 lineto
200 300 lineto
closepath

stroke
showpage
```

One special effect you may be able to achieve by combining a rectangle with the clippath is to do a fill of the *exterior* of the rectangle. There's a small implementation dependency on the orientation (CW vs. CCW) of the clipping path.

```
clippath  % set current path to be the clipping path
reversepath  % may need to reverse the rectangle depending on implementation

200 300 moveto
400 300 lineto
400 450 lineto
200 450 lineto
200 300 lineto
closepath

eofill
showpage
```

Comment: Thank you so very much @Iuser droog for taking the time to take my question; deeply appreciate it. I have a few questions regarding your answers. 1. your first paragraph: Your comment is "clippath appends the current clipping path to the current path" whereas the spec is "sets the current path to the current clipping path". Could you elaborate? 2. your second paragraph: I am learning PS programming and try to understand what the operators accomplish. I run into this question actually trying to get the fill outside the rectangle which you mentioned in your reply.

Comment: 3. my rectangle completes, why closepath is needed for stroke? 4. I tried your code snippet with the reversepath, I still get the fill of the whole medium, instead of the interior of the rectangle or the area between the boundary of the medium and the rectangl

Comment: 200 300 moveto
400 300 lineto
400 450 lineto
200 450 lineto
200 300 lineto
closepath

reversepath 
clippath

fill
showpage

Comment: I tried both fill and eofill, I got the fill of the whole page from your code 200 300 moveto
400 300 lineto
400 450 lineto
200 450 lineto
200 300 lineto
closepath

reversepath 
clippath  

fill
showpage

How to enter a newline here in the post? I have to copy it from you post, hahaha

Comment: I still cannot achieve the fill of the exterior of the rectangle.

Comment: Oops. You're right. I remembered it wrong. `clippath` sets the path to the clipping path. So that obliterates the rectangle right there. ... Then it ought to work if we reverse the order: call `clippath` first (then maybe 'reversepath') and then do `... moveto ... lineto ...etc` which appends new segments to the path.

Comment: You can see the effect of closepath on a stroke of a rectangle by setting the linewidth to be very large. You will see that the first (last) corner doesn't have a nice join, instead just two linecaps that are near to each other.

Comment: Yes, I see the difference between with closepath and without closepath. Thank you. That's coming from experience. I don't think the spec would mention it.

Comment: @luer droog I still don't get the fill of exterior of the rectangle though. Can you help? No matter what I tried with the combination of clip/eoclip, fill/eofill, clippath, reversepath, I could not get the fill of the exterior of the rectangle.

Comment: @luer droog I got it work %!PS-Adobe-3.0
200 300 moveto
400 300 lineto
400 450 lineto
200 450 lineto
200 300 lineto
closepath

250 350 moveto
350 350 lineto
350 400 lineto
250 400 lineto
250 350 lineto
closepath

eofill
showpage
but I don't understand why adding reversepath after the inner rectangleand then fill instead of eofill won't work.

Comment: That part is very weird and hard to understand. Many graphics systems use the definitions, though, so searching for "even-odd winding rule" and "non-zero winding rule" should find lots of explanation. By reversing a subpath, it can change the winding number for that region. So, if the large rectangle goes CCW and the smaller rectangle inside of it goes CW, then the region in the center will have winding number 0, because the inter-shape region is winding number 1. Using `eofill` instead, you can make both rectangles the same orientation; the winding numbers will be 1 and 2, so even-odd works.

Comment: You are right on both fronts; one that even-odd works and two, it's weird why non-zero winding does not work as expected.